# Vue.js refs are undefined, even though this.$refs shows theyre there

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a reference to a component

```vue
<Gmap ref="mapRef">
```

In mounted I am doing this, to see the objects are available

```vue
mounted(){
    let self = this
    console.log(self.$refs) // Shows the mapRef object reference
    console.log(self.$refs.mapRef) // returns undefined ???
}
```

self.$refs shows...

```
  mapRef: VueComponent {_uid: 207, _isVue: true, $options: {…}, _renderProxy: Proxy, _self: VueComponent, …}
```

So then why does `self.$refs.mapRef`  return undefined??
Even though it's clearly there??

Comment: What about plain old `this.$refs`?

Comment: Can you make a snippet or fiddle that demonstrates the problem? I can't replicate it in a snippet.

Comment: this.$refs is the same thing.  So no...it shows the same thing,  Also...no I cant replicate it in JsFiddle either.  Its just in my project that its happening.  Ugh....so frutstrating

Comment: _Note that mounted does not guarantee that all child components have also been mounted_. [docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted)

Comment: @ljubadr - actually according to [this](https://medium.com/@brockreece/vue-parent-and-child-lifecycle-hooks-5d6236bd561f) it waits. Can you provider any doc to support your statement ?

Comment: I did provide the link, but here it is again [mounted docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted)

Comment: so medium's article seems to be not correct

Comment: Yup, always check the docs first, had similar experience with random articles

Comment: Instead of `console.log()` use `debugger` (or place a breakpoint), and inspect the values

Comment: You can look into [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23392111/console-log-async-or-sync). `console.log` has some quirks

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I solved this by using v-show instead of v-if.

I had the  component inside a v-if statement.

```
 <div v-if="!isLoading"> 
   <GMap ref="mapRef" />
 </div>
```

I just changed that to v-show

```
<div v-show="!isLoading"> 
   <GMap ref="mapRef" />
 </div>
```

And now the object is available in mounted().  Still find it strange that the console.log(this.$refs) showed it being available as a key on this.$refs, even though it actually wasn't? Thats strange behaviour.

The other wierd thing was, that even if I tried to access this.$refs.mapRef in my data loading section, AFTER THE DATA WAS LOADED, (ie after isLoading=false), I still couldn't access it.  Even though then, it should've been available because the v-if passed.

So v-show solved it, by just hiding the div, instead of not rendereding it.  Stupid little workaround.

Comment: `this.$refs` is filled after being mounted. The console.log shows the current version of  an object, when you open it. Try the following: `let a = {foo: 1};
console.log(a);
a.bar = 2;`
It will result in an a with both foo and bar properties.

Comment: This is obviously way late, but for anyone else reading that last comment from @StefanJanssen the way you can make sure to `console.log()` and get the current value is to use `JSON.stringify()` like: `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.$refs))` as that will output a string that can't get updated in the console like Stefan's example.

Comment: oh jesus i have spent so much time for such a stupid mistake

Answer (score 22):

I had a similar problem getting a ref to a leaflet map instance, try waiting for the "nextTick"

```
mounted(){
  this.$nextTick(()=>{
    let self = this
    console.log(self.$refs) // Shows the mapRef object reference
    console.log(self.$refs.mapRef) // returns undefined ???
  });
}
```

see the docs for more- https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-nextTick
and https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted

Comment: nah, still returns undefined.  Im stumped :(

Comment: Ive tried jsFiddle.  And it works there.  It appears to only be happening in my project unfortunately.  Im using vue2-google-maps component for the map.  So maybe its something to do with that particular components lifecycle or something like that?? Not too sure.

Comment: I looked at the vue2-google-maps repo, and it looks like a similar issue was addressed with nextTick being the main answer, but maybe some of the responses here will help - https://github.com/xkjyeah/vue-google-maps/issues/260

Comment: I solved it, the referenced GMap was inside a v-if statement.  I changed it to v-show and it works now.   Wierd that the console.log(this.$refs) still showed it as "being there" though.

Answer (score 14):

Main solution is to **make sure your component is not imported dynamically**

You'd still need to also avoid wrapping your component with `v-if` and use `this.$refs.mapRef` in `mounted()`, instead of `created()`

I wasn't using Vue Google Maps plugin/component, but my own custom component

---

#### Method 1

Use:

```
import CustomComponent from './CustomComponent ';

export default {
  components: {
    CustomComponent,
  },
  ...
}
```

Instead of

```
export default {
  components: {
    CustomComponent: () => import('./CustomComponent'),
  },
  ...
}
```

---

#### Method 2

Use `this.$refs.mapRef` in `mounted()` instead of `created()`.

This way, `setTimeout()` and `this.$nextTick()` not needed

Correct way:

```js
mounted(){
  //works! child components were loaded
  console.log(this.$refs.mapRef) 
}
```

Wrong way:

```js
created(){
  //DON'T DO THIS! child components hasn't loaded
  console.log(this.$refs.mapRef) 

  //might work but it's an unreliable workaround
  setTimeout(()=>{
    console.log(this.$refs.mapRef)
  }, 0);

  //might work but it's an unreliable workaround
  this.$nextTick(()=>{
    console.log(this.$refs.mapRef)
  });

}
```

---

#### Method 3

Do not wrap child component using `v-if`, use `v-show` instead.

Correct way:

```js
 <div v-show="!isLoading"> 
   <GMap ref="mapRef" />
 </div>
```

Wrong way:

```js
 <div v-if="!isLoading"> 
   <GMap ref="mapRef" />
 </div>
```

---

#### Other Methods (not proper & not a solution)

The following are methods I tried but didn't work until I used the methods on top (stopped using dynamic import)

I already put `this.$refs.mapRef` in `mounted()` tried to wrap it with `setTimeout()` and 2 layers of `this.$nextTick()`.

It works only on hot reload, but no longer works after a page refresh

```
mounted(){
  setTimeout(()=>{
    this.$nextTick(()=>{
      this.$nextTick(()=>{
        console.log(this.$refs.mapRef) // returns undefined
      });
    });
  }, 0);
}
```

Thanks to this comment in another answer:
[How to access to a child method from the parent in vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40957008/how-to-access-to-a-child-method-from-the-parent-in-vue-js/40957171#comment104087940_47565763)

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your function in the `$mapPromise` method provided by `vue2-google-maps`, which will ensure that the Map has fully rendered before running your code:

```
let self = this;
self.$refs.mapRef.$mapPromise.then(() => {
    console.log(self.$refs.mapRef);
})
```

This should solve any problem where your code relies the Google Map to be fully rendered in order to run.

*NOTE: `$mapPromise` was named `$mapCreated` in past versions.

See Docs: https://github.com/Jeson-gk/vue2-google-maps/blob/master/API.md#mapcreated--promisegooglemapsmap

-

The **reason** why `console.log(self.$refs);` was showing the value when you looked, is that `self.$refs` is passed by reference. So, by the time you viewed the console, the rest of the data finished loading in a matter of milliseconds. And `self.$ref.mapRef` is not passed by reference, so it remains `undefined`, as it was during runtime.

Try adding a **breakpoint** directly after `console.log(self.$refs);` and before `console.log(self.$refs.mapRef);` and you will probably find that the data had not loaded.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using ref along with v-for, I missed the fact ref is generated only after v-for is rendered in the dom, and I was using v-for with a state array property which is populated a few seconds after mounted is called and I was trying to access my ref before the populating the state array.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're using: https://github.com/diegoazh/gmap-vue, as the docs says: https://diegoazh.github.io/gmap-vue/#lazy-loading

```
async mounted() {
    await this.$gmapApiPromiseLazy()

    ...
}
```

This works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You could add `eager` prop to the component, because of lazy loading in vuetify 2.

Answer (score -5):

You can use it as follows, though I don't know if in anyway it could break typescript implementation for commercial projects.

```
(this as any).$refs.mapRef
```

Comment: but this completely has nothing to do with the problem.