# Current slide number of total in Vue Slick Carousel

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to make current number and total number of slides  using vue-slick-carousel.
This is what I tried so far.

```
<VueSlickCarousel ref="carousel">
<div>1 <button tabindex="-1">11</button></div>
<div>2 <button tabindex="-1">22</button></div>
<div>3 <button tabindex="-1">33</button></div>
<div>4<button tabindex="-1">44</button></div>
</VueSlickCarousel>


methods: {
    customPaging: function (slider, i) {
      var slideNumber = i + 1,
        totalSlides = slider.slideCount;
      return (
        '<a class="custom-dot" role="button" title="' + slideNumber + ' of ' + totalSlides + '"><span class="string">' + slideNumber + '</span></a>'
      );
    },
},
```

But this is not working.

And this is vue-slick-carousel API url below.

https://github.com/gs-shop/vue-slick-carousel/blob/master/docs/API.md#methods

What do i need to fixed the code  to show a current slide number and total slide.
ex) "3/10"

Comment: what about `this.$refs.carousel.$el.children.length`?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem recently.
This probably comes late, but to whom it may still concern:

If you want to display current page numbers instead of the default dots, there is an example at the bottom of this [VueSlickCarousel documentation page](https://gs-shop.github.io/vue-slick-carousel/#/api) and you should be good.

If you want to display the current page number only once anywhere on your page, I found a solution that worked for me:

`this.$refs` solution did not work for me, but this was likely due to `v-if` that I was using to render the `<VueSlickCarousel>`.
`v-if` and `this.$refs` don't like each other very much - see also [Vue.js refs are undefined, even though this.$refs shows they're there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54355375/vue-js-refs-are-undefined-even-though-this-refs-shows-theyre-there).

Eventually I tried looking at the events that the children emitted in Vue Devtools and I found this [afterChange event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTWQL.png).

The `afterChange` event is fired each time you move your carousel to the next page (regardless of whether you drag-slide or click the arrow) and contains a very useful `param` - the current page index. In my case, this param starts at 0 and for each change it is incremented or decremented by 3 - that is because my carrousel settings are set to `slidesToScroll : 3`.

So my solution was to:

1. Add event listener like this:
   `<VueSlickCarousel @afterChange="afterPageChange">`
2. Create the `sliderPageIndex` in your data with the initial value 0.

```js
data() {
  return {
    sliderPageIndex: 0;
  }
}
```

3. Create the `afterPageChange` in `methods: {}`.

```js
methods: {
  afterPageChange(page) {
    this.sliderPageIndex = page;
  }
}
```

4. Create the `currentPage` in `computed: {}` with some additional logic to compensate for the abovementioned `slidesToScroll` setting and for the `sliderPageIndex` starting at 0, like this:

```js
computed: {
  currentPage() {
    // always display 1 if page index is 0
    if (this.sliderPageIndex == 0) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      // compensate for slidesToScroll settings and compensate the shift by 1
      return this.sliderPageIndex / this.carouselSettings.slidesToScroll + 1;
    }
  },
}
```

Now you should have access to the `currentPage` computed property and can use it anywhere in your `<template>`.

When it comes to the `totalPages`, I compute it from the length of the picture array that I send to the carousel instead of taking it from the carousel directly. Here, I also compensate for `carouselSettings` - if this requires further explanation, let me know.

You can read more about the VueSlickCarousel events [here](https://gs-shop.github.io/vue-slick-carousel/#/api).
Hope this will be of use to someone! :)

Cheers and have a nice day.