# VueJS extends component with slots

Tags: vue.js

I have a BaseModal Component like this :

```
<template>
    <div class="base-modal" :class="{open: isOpen}">
        <div class="modal">
            <h2 class="modal-title">
                <slot name="title"></slot>
            </h2>
            <div class="modal-content">
                <slot name="content"></slot>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>


<script lang="ts">
    import { Vue, Component } from "vue-property-decorator";

    @Component({})
    export default class BaseModal extends Vue {

        public isOpen: boolean = false;

        // Some methods

    }
</script>
```

I want to create an other modal component that will extend this one and pass it the content for the named slots. Here is where I am :

```
<template>
    // How to give slots content here
</template>


<script lang="ts">
    import BaseModal from "@app/components/BaseModal.vue";
    import { Vue, Prop, Component } from "vue-property-decorator";

    @Component({
        extends: BaseModal,
    })
    export default class OtherDropdown extends Vue {
    }
</script>
```

The extends is working but I can't figure out how to pass content to the named slot of the extended component. Not to have to write again all the BaseModal template.

Thanks

I'm using VueJS 2.6.8

Answer (score 1):

You would want to use components named slots like this:

```
<template>
  <BaseModal>
    <template v-slot:title>
      Some Title
    </template>
    
    <template v-slot:content>
      Some content goes here
    </template>
  </BaseModal>
</template>
```

You can read more about named slots here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Named-Slots

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is already what I'm doing in the code of the example. Here you don't extend the component you just use it in an other component.

Comment: @Mushr00m - I don't believe `@extends`, in this instance is proper to use. You're effectively overwriting the parent template with your child component by using extends. I believe the proper way of doing this is HOC and slots, as shown

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My issue with this technique is that my component `Foo` using `OtherDropdown` that uses `BaseModal` cannot call `open()` method. Because the `BaseModal` is nested inside the `OtherDropdown` component. So the parent doesn't have access to methods even using `$refs`. How would you to to make `OtherDropdown` having access to all `BaseModal` methods without rewritting them ?

Comment: Have You figured it out already? Using `$refs` should work I believe as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47565763/1505369 . I believe it could also be possible to pass the whole `this` element with `v-model`, which means emitting some event after initialization, but it seems like a quite a dirty solution to me.