# Vue expose a method from child component to parent component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

Among the approaches below, which do you think is better practice ??

**[ 1 ]** Using `$emit`  to expose methods from child component to parent component

```
$emit('updateAPI',  exposeAPI({ childMethod: this.childMethod }))
```

**OR**

**[ 2 ]** Using `$refs` from parent component to access child component methods

```
this.$refs.childComponent.childMethod()
```

Comment: You should read the answer over here.Everything is explained really well for understanding. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40957008/how-to-access-to-a-child-method-from-the-parent-in-vue-js/40957171

Comment: Emit - definitely. It completely decouples the parent and child element to increase reusability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About **$refs**, according to the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html):

> "$refs are only populated after the component has been rendered, and
> they are not reactive. It is only meant as an escape hatch for direct
> child manipulation - you should avoid accessing $refs from within
> templates or computed properties."

About **callbacks**, I have no information about cons and there is a nice example in script section of [this component](https://v1.quasar-framework.org/vue-components/slide-item) of Quasar Framework, which parent component recieves via emit a function called `reset` and can dispatch this child function. That's why I think this way is preferable.

Comment: yes.. thank you.. i got it.... BTW so far i'm using `` $refs ``only for call focus();