# (Vue.js 3 Options API) How do I access a child method?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-options-api

I need to access a child component's method using Vue.js 3 with Options API. There is an answer at [How to access to a child method from the parent in vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40957008/how-to-access-to-a-child-method-from-the-parent-in-vue-js), but it is for Vue.js 2 and Vue.js 3 but with Composition API.

I still tried this, all in the parent component:

```
<dropdown-list @update="updateChildComponents"></dropdown-list>
<child-component-1 ref="childComponent1Ref" :url="url"></child-component-1>
<child-component-2 ref="childComponent2Ref" :url="url"></child-component-2>
```

and

```
methods: {
  updateChildComponents() {
    this.$refs.childComponent1Ref.childComponentMethod();
    this.$refs.childComponent2Ref.childComponentMethod();
  }
}
```

This actually successfully accesses the method, but I think this may not be the right way.

Secondly, I use a prop in the child component that I update in the parent and use in the child component's method, which updates only after the second event. I think these two may be related.

Child component:

```
props: ['url'],
methods: {
  childComponentMethod() {
    console.log(this.url); // can access the value from the previous event 
  }
}
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Why not to use on and emit? There are good examples in the question you mentioned

Comment: @Thescion I edited my answer. Using emit I can communicate from child to parent, I need the opposite.

Comment: If you are changing the value in the parent, can't you see it rendering in the  child? You try to add watch in the children?

Comment: There should basically be `url` watcher in child component that logs it. If your case differs consider updating the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For communication between the parent and the children you should trasfer the value with props. In case the value is changing in the parent you must add watch.
It called 1 way binding because the parent cant see the changes in the child component.

Parent -> child = use props.

Child -> parent = use emits and on event.

```
<script>
import { reactive,watch, computed,onMounted } from "vue";


export default {
  components: { 
  },
  props: { metadata: String },
  emits: [""],
  setup(props) {
    onMounted(async () => {
    //first initilize 
      if (props.metadata) {
        state.metadataName = props.metadata;
      }
    });
    //track after the changes in the parent
    watch(
      () => props.metadata,
      async (metadata) => {
        if (metadata) {
          
        }
      }
    );
    return {
     
    };
  },
};
</script>
```